# Find original message in RSA when given 2 cipher text and public keys differ in 1 bit

Tags: cryptography, rsa

Using RSA,
**Known that:**

- `K_1` - public key
- `K_2` - public key
- `C_1` = `E(M,K_1)` - Cipher text
- `C_2` = `E(M,K_2)` - Cipher text
- **Keys K_1 and K_2 are only different in one bit** (we don't know which bit).

How can I find the original plain-text M?
**Note: Brute-force can't be used.**

I read somewhere that
`r*K_1 + s*K_2 = 1 modN,` and `r` (or `s`) may be negative too.

**Thus, M can be found like that**:    `((C_1 )^-1)^-r * (C_2)^s = M`

**Note:** `((C_1 )^-1)` can be computed from `C_1` and so `M` can be computed.

Questions: Who said that `gcd(K_1,K_2) = 1,` then how could it be true that `r*K_1 + s*K_2 = 1 modN`?

Second, if that solution isn't true, anyone can tell me how could he have approach that question?

Comment: The K_1 is called public modulus not public key, the public key for RSA is a pair (n,e) that is in your case (N,k_1) or (N,k_2)

Comment: @kelalaka Yup, you are right. Thx

Comment: What are K_1 and K_2? Are they public keys, public exponents, moduli... what? Also, this doesn't appear to be a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that K_1 and K_2 are are legal keys, the following should exists:

`gcd(K_1, φ(φ(N))=1` and `gcd(K_2, φ(N))=1` where `φ` is the Euler's totient function.

Given that, we know that K_1 and K_2 must be **odd**. With the info that these keys differ only by 1 bit, we know that `gcd(K_1, K_2)=1`. This means that `r s` exists such as `rK_1 + sK_2 = 1` (definition of `gcd`).

We know that `C_1 = E(M,K_1)` and `C_2 = E(M,K_2)`.

Let's multiply `C_1^r` by `C_2^s` and see what we get:

```
C_1^r * C_2^s = (M^K_1)^r * (M^K_2)^s = M^(rK_1 + sK_2) = M^1 = M
```

We found original message M.

Comment: How do you know that K_1 and K_2 must be even? If they are even, differ only one bit, and that is not LSB then gcd(K_1, K_2) is at least 2!

Comment: Because they are relatively prime @kelalaka

Comment: @kelalaka I mean that they must be odd because a valid key used for encryption, must have the property 'gcd(K_1, φ(φ(N))=1'. Since this is RSA, N consists of two prime numbers bigger than 2. That means φ(φ(N)) will be even and since gcd with  φ(φ(N)) is 1, we have to conclude that the key is odd. I typed even by mistake.